# To what extent is phenomenology capable of advancing empirically testable (i.e. falsifiable) hypotheses?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, phenomenology

Otherwise, to the extent it cannot, what is its utility?

Comment: Phenomenology develops an approach to phenomena that are only accessible through introspection, and hence are neither repeatable nor reproducible. So direct testing is not an option, but the phenomena do exist and have to be studied somehow. The frameworks developed, although speculative, are  an improvement on "folk psychology", and so useful for generating hypotheses in neuroscience and cognitive psychology. Related [How should science approach non-empirical phenomena?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/32738/9148)